# Execute a specifict task that did not exist before

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to execute only a specific task in Airflow.

This task was added to the DAG some days later than I created the DAG, so, there's no execution from a time before.

Example:

[image: Tasks]

I tried to achieve this with the "backfill" command from Airflow to execute only the task B, but, if I use this, backfill ignores the days where that task didn't exist.

Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you hav already dag_run on that execute date, so backfill ignore  it. You can clear all dag runs and then backfill (all tasks in each dag would run).

Comment: When I use the "--reset-dagruns" option with the backfill command, still ignoring the days were the task didn't exist.